# Landing page with App Showcase

Tags: javascript, css, frameworks

I'm not quite good in javascript or css but I would like to create a home page with an iPhone. When you scroll through the page, the view scroll in the iPhone.
It will be exactly like this one : https://www.happn.com/it/

I have nothing yet and I'm searching for framework or anything that could help me to do it the simpliest way possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is something like scrollspy for Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Mostly depending on the scroll position they modify the iPhone graphics. It could be just an animation that they loop forward and backward depending on the the position of the scroll. You take a look at: http://framework7.io/ but I believe it can be done easierly done with an animation.